# escaping html tags inside xslt:value-of select

Tags: qt4, xslt

I am converting text inside a XML document element (*which also contains other texts not only a hyperlink*) to hyperlink using the following:

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="replace(AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION, 
                     '(abc@yahoo.com)', 
                     '&lt;a href=&quot;$1&quot;&gt;$1&lt;/a&gt;')"/>
```

XML Source:

```
<AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION>Plugin author can be reached at abc@yahoo.com for his email.</AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot escape the '<' & '>' tags used in a href. My XSLT processor is Qt4's QXmlQuery class. It seems it doesn't support 'disable-output-escaping' attribute in the above expression and I can't seem to find any other way than to manually parse the final output and replace each '&lt' & '&gt' with '<' & '>' using C++ code.

PS: Couldn't get 'analyse-string' to work in qt either. It just returns empty string. Refered to http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/rev2/regex2.html question 3 and used the following:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION" regex="(abc@yahoo.com)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <a href="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></a>
    </xsl:matching-substring>

    <xsl:non-matching-substring>  
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

The above works fine in 'Altova XMLSpy' doing exactly what I want. But in Qt4, the output has empty string (To be more accurate my <td> tag before this expression is also mysteriously gone in the output, weird). Qt4 documentation says its processor supports 'xsl:analyze-string'. Any one have a working example of 'xsl:analyze-string' in Qt?

Qt4 documentation says its processor doesn't support 'xsl:character-map' so no point going there.

Without 'xsl:analyze-string' working I am back to square one with 'replace()'.

-Sanjeev

Comment: I'm bad with 2.0, but may be [xsl:character-map](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-character-map) can be helpful.

Comment: You can't create tags by generating `&lt;` like this. You'll need to output an actual tag (i.e. `<a href='(regex match)'>(regex match)</a>`.

Comment: What is your input, what output do you want to create? It might be that the `xsl:analyze-string` http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string can help if your aim is to parse plain text with a regular expression to build a link element from it in the output.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and for a proper way to do this.

Comment: @Sanjeev: From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-value-of: *The `xsl:value-of` instruction is evaluated to construct a new text node; the result of the instruction is the newly constructed text node.* **You can't output elements nor element's tags from an instruction for output text nodes.** You are right about you must use `analyze-string` instruction.

Comment: Thanks guys for answering. I have added more info in my original post. Please re-read it.

Comment: @Sanjeev: Whenever you define this question properly, you can get an XSLT 1.0 solution that *might* work with Qt4, as you have shown that it isn't a compliant XSLT 2.0 processor. Right now you haven't provided enough relevant information and the question in its current form has been completely answerd in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Hi all, I am converting text inside a
>   XML document element to hyperlink
>   using the following:
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="replace(AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION,
> ```
>
> '(RegEx here)', '<a
>   href="$1">$1</a>')"
>
> Unfortunately, I cannot escape the '<'
>   & '>' tags used in a href

**The short answer**: You shouldn't even try to do that.

Escaping markup is demoting it to one-dimensional text and it will only show as text in a browser.

**The proper way to do this** is to generate the markup as  (a sequence of) literal result elements:

```
<xsl:template match="AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION">
  <a href="{someExpression}"><xsl:value-of select="someExpr2"/></a>
</xsl:template>
```

**UPDATE**: The OP has provided more information about the real problem. The problem is that thie following is "not working" on his XSLT processor -- Qt4 ???

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION" regex="(abc@yahoo.com)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <a href="{.}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </a>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

**I have verified that this codes behaves as expected** and produces the expected result when run under Saxon 9.1.05.

This means that Qt4 is not a compliant XSLT 2.0 processor.

**Here I can offer the following alternative solution**, which works both with an XSLT 1.0 processor and an XSLT 2.0 processor:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "substring-before(., 'abc@yahoo.com')"/>
  <a href="abc@yahoo.com">abc@yahoo.com</a>
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "substring-after(., 'abc@yahoo.com')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION>Plugin author can be reached at abc@yahoo.com for his email.</AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced** (with all 8 different XSLT processors I have at hand):

```
Plugin author can be reached at <a href="abc@yahoo.com">abc@yahoo.com</a> for his email.
```

Comment: I am not sure how this will help Dimitre. Where do I put my RegEx? May be my question wasn't clearer. I have added more info on my original post. Could you please re-read it?

Comment: @Sanjeev: I have updated my answer and am providing an alternative solution that might work with your problematic XSLT processor.

Comment: @Dimitre: Apparently, 'abc@yahoo.com' isn't the only thing I wanna convert to hyperlink. It's just an example. What I wanna convert to 'a href' ranges from hyperlinks to email addresses so the solution should be capable of having Regular Expressions to find and replace those into 'a href' tag. Again, there might be multiple hyperlinks and email addresses. For example: <AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION>The author's email is xyz@abc.com and his weblink is [http://something.com/](http://something.com/)</AUTHOR_CONTACT_INFORMATION>

Comment: @Sanjeev: Then you need to re-define your question, and define it well this time. You are obviously out of luck with Qt4 -- BTW, I've never heard of such XSLT processor -- are you sure it is an XSLT **2** processor?. Anyway, this thing could be possible to do in pure XSLT 1.0 if you define your problem well. I have been doing for years tokenization, justification, spelling-checking of text, so your tasks sounds not more complex than these.

Comment: @Dimitre: I agree that my problem shouldn't be complex to solve but somehow I've managed to get stuck in this problem for two days now. The question is simple, I wanna extract all email and hyperlinks from a text element of XML using **Regular Expressions** and replace them with HTML 'a href's. You've probably not heard about [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) is because it's a C++ cross-platform library for writing desktop application and only parts of it is related to web technology.

Comment: @Sanjeev: This is not a question -- just a statement. I assume that your question is "How to do this with Qt4". This question is not an XSLT question at all, because you have shown evidence that Qt4 is not a compliant XSLT (2) processor. If you want to try Qt4 as an XSLT 1.0 processor, then you must ask for an XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: @Dimitre: Then what could be an XSLT 1.0 solution?

Comment: @Sanjeev: I already gave you one XSLT 1.0 solution in my answer. If you specify better your problem, then you will get corresponding XSLT 1.0 solutions, too. What is under question is whether your Qt4 ??? will function as a compliant XSLT 1.0 processor.